# How do I get two values from same text field?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to GUI and trying to make a calculator in JFrame but whenever I perform the addition operation it says that the string is empty.If I remove `"jTextField1.setText("");"` part it works fine but the previous text is still on the text field. Is there a way I could create another instance of text field or something like that to accommodate the second string?

```
 private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        a=Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
         jTextField1.setText("");
        b=Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        res=a+b; 

    }
```

Comment: you should preform the addition first within the event handler, and then send the sum to the text field. 

The sum is what should be used with getText.

Comment: Are you trying to get an entire expression from a text field ("1+2") or are you trying to get two values from two different text fields? Right now, your code seems to try to get two different values from one text field, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556) for ideas.  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Comment: David I am trying to get two values from same text field. After the operand button is pressed I want to clear the text field and want the user to enter second value in the same text field.

Comment: *"David I am trying.."* Tip: Add @DavidConrad (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. (BTW - voting to close.)

Comment: Then you can't immediately read the second value from the field. You haven't given the user any time to enter a second value. You would have to clear the field and then, after they enter the second value, they could press the button again, or press another button, to let you know the second value was ready to be read from the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code.

```
enter code here

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Calculation_ActionEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JFrame f;
JLabel l;
JTextField tf1, tf3;
JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;

Calculation_ActionEvent(String s) {
    f = new JFrame(s);
    f.setLayout(null);
    l = new JLabel("Enter two numbers : ");
    tf1 = new JTextField();
    // tf2 = new JTextField();
    tf3 = new JTextField();
    b1 = new JButton("+");
    b2 = new JButton("-");
    b3 = new JButton("*");
    b4 = new JButton("/");
    b5 = new JButton("equals");
    b6 = new JButton("C");
    f.add(l);
    f.add(tf1);
    f.add(tf3);
    f.add(b1);
    f.add(b2);
    f.add(b3);
    f.add(b4);
    f.add(b5);
    f.add(b6);
    tf1.setBounds(160, 100, 250, 30);
    // tf2.setBounds(320,100,50,30);
    tf3.setBounds(250, 420, 50, 30);
    b1.setBounds(250, 180, 50, 30);
    b2.setBounds(350, 260, 50, 30);
    b3.setBounds(150, 260, 50, 30);
    b4.setBounds(250, 340, 50, 30);
    b5.setBounds(230, 260, 90, 30);
    b6.setBounds(420, 100, 50, 30);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    f.setSize(550, 550);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

int total = 0;
String lastAction = "";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int num = 0;
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {}
    String s1 = e.getActionCommand();
    if (s1.equals("C")) {
        tf1.setText("");
        tf3.setText("0");
        tf1.requestFocus();
        total = 0;
    } else if (s1.equals("equals")) {
        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(calc(total, lastAction, num)));
        tf1.setText("");
        tf1.requestFocus();
        total = 0;
    } else {
        total = total==0 ? num : calc(total, lastAction, num);
        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        tf1.setText("");
        tf1.requestFocus();
        lastAction = s1;
    }
}

private int calc(int num1, String action, int num2) {
    switch (action) {
    case "+":
        return num1 + num2;
    case "-":
        return num1 - num2;
    case "*":
        return num1 * num2;
    case "/":
        return num1 / num2;
    default:
        return num1;
    }
}

public static void main(String... s) {
    new Calculation_ActionEvent("Calculator");
}
```

}

Comment: Doesnt really address to the issue I am having.